# apply class attribute to children for jquery 1.3.2

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

am i doing something wrong here? I am trying to apply a class attribute to the children of #one

```
<div id="one">
<div id="first"></div>
<div id="second"></div>
</div>

jquery---
$('#one').children().attr('class' , 'className');
```

Comment: As per the downvote `[title]` text: "This question does not show any research effort"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `.addClass` Its been in jQuery since v1.0

```
 $('#one').children().addClass('className');
```

See [Here](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) for jQuery's documentation on the matter.

Comment: heh 30 seconds to low to get the thumbs up :p

Comment: :-) i guess i acted totally dumb on this question ...should have researched it littlebit more...i mean it was such a simple thing...and just acted lazy i guess

Answer (score 5):

try this:

```
$(function(){
    $('#one').children().addClass('className');
});
```

Comment: thanks for the quick response...i should have done littlebit more research on this before writing this question..apologies